# Require is not defined error in Visual Studio when using ReactJS

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, gulp

I have a *helloworld.jsx* file built successfully into a js file and is included in a page through the script tag.

When I run the page in Chrome, I get the following error. Should I include any other Bower package to use **require**.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

```
var React = require('react');

var HelloWorld = React.createClass({displayName: "HelloWorld",
    render: function () {
        return (React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello World"));
    }
});

var parent = document.querySelector('#greeting');
React.renderComponent(React.createElement(HelloWord, null), parent);
```

Comment: Do you have webpack/browserify or some other package manager setup? If not you should just use a script tag or look at setting one up.

Comment: I directly dropped the reference to the react.js file which is working. I don't have webpack/browserify installed, but installed babel. But still giving the error, so I assume I have to install RequireJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into getting started and see how to setup React for use in browser: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html

In order to use `require` you need to setup browserify/webpack compilation in your development process, both of them properly transform `require` into single bundle file.